# What is wrong with the colors?

Tags: faces

It looks as if the colors are inverted, but I don't know if that's lighting or how to fix it. There ARE faces there, but I don't know why they are appearing wrong.

[image: The Issue]

[image: from the inside]

Comment: If none of the 

1. remove doubles, 

2. turning on subsurface modifier (and looking for peculiar topology), 

3. recalculating normals, 

does not work, I recommend you upload the .blend file with http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: does this only occur in edit mode?

Answer (score -2):

It appears that you are in orthographic view press 5 on numpad to exit this view

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.